# Strange issue with table in PHPMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having an issue with a table within my database whereas I cannot execute any queries against it. 
I checked my syntax multiplie times and after discovering there was no problem with it I went into PHPMyadmin and have uncovered the following issue which I have not come across before.

When I try to browse the rows in my table (of which there are over 2000) it won't let me browse and comes up with the following error. This is even when I click the table name in the list in the left menu.

[image]

As you can see it is trying to organise the rows using an ORDER BY whenever I try and access the table and I don't know why it is trying to do this.

Can anybody shed any light on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `order by` clause does not contain column name

Comment: Hi, I can see the ORDER BY is the issue but I am not executing an SQL command on the table. I get this error just when I try to browse the records within the table. It's applying the ORDER BY itself and I'm unsure why

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this issue by deleting and re-creating the table but am still unsure as to why it was adding a default ORDER BY whenever I was trying to access the table.
If anybody could shed any light on this it would be very helpful if it were to happen again!
Thanks